# Name of a metric space concept

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I have a metric space with the following property (a bit like having unique geodesics): for any points $a,b,x,y$ with $d(a,b)=d(a,x)+d(x,b)=d(a,y)+d(y,b)$ and $d(a,x)=d(a,y)$, we have $x=y$.  Is there an established name for this?

(UPDATE: the condition $d(a,x)=d(a,y)$ was omitted by mistake in the original question.)

Comment: Uhm. One-point set?

Comment: To elucidate Darij's comment: you probably want to add the condition $d(a,x) = d(a,y)$.

Comment: No time to check, but it looks related to Definition 2.6 in this paper: http://home.lu.lv/~ibula/lv/petnieciba/raksti/moravica.pdf

Comment: Not the same though: any subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the Euclidean metric satisfies this property but not the one in the Bula paper.

Comment: Oh yes -- it's like the uniqueness part of strict convexity but not the existence part. It's probably too much to hope that a metric space with Neil's property can be isometrically embedded into a strictly convex metric space in Bula's sense.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to prove that the completion of your space can be any separable metric space 
where metric spheres are nowhere dense.

> Does not it scare you?

**Answer to the comment:**
Not all of your spaces can be embedded into a metric tree.

BTW, there is a nice characterization of subsets in a metric tree:
$$ | x - y | + | a - b | \le \max\{|x-a| + |y-b|,|x-b|+|y-a|\}$$
for all points $x,y,a,b$
(here $|x-y|$ denotes the distance from $x$ to $y$).

In other words, the values 
$$X=|x-a|+|y-b|,$$
$$Y=|x-b|+|y-a|,$$ 
$$Z=|x-y|+|a-b|$$ satisfy [ulrtatriangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_inequality).
This inequality  can be also thought as a discrete analog of CAT[−∞] inequality.

Comment: Not really.  The particular class of spaces that I am thinking about arise in a very combinatorial way, and I hope to show that each of them is the vertex set of a tree with the obvious edge-counting metric.  (In particular, my spaces have only finitely many points.) I have proved the property in my question as a step towards that.

Comment: I will answer above. 

Comment: Doesn't a 4-cycle satisfy that inequality?

Comment: Ups, now it is correct.